# Alter a table via css

Tags: html, css

im having this table from woocommerce products receipt print, and i have the following problem: Quantity column has a width: 15% value, but it looks like it takes 30% of the tables width and take alot of useful space.

does anyone have an idea why thats happening?

Also, how can i remove the 'price' column entirely via css without shrinking the table (keeping it 100% width)

There's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ay7ys32L/2/

HTML:

```
    <div id="page">





                <article class="content">

                    ﻿                   
                    <div class="company-info">
                        <h1 class="company-name">Flouskounis Food</h1>                      <div class="company-address"><p>2610 424342, Νοταρά 85</p>
</div>
                    </div>

                <div class="order-addresses">

                    <div class="billing-address">
                        <h3>Πελάτης:</h3>
                        <address>

                            customer name<br/>Κυρία<br/>address<br/>ισόγειο<br/>city<br/>Πελοπόννησος<br/>26225
                        </address>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- .order-addresses -->
                phone               
                <div class="order-items">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="head-quantity"><span>quantity</span></th>
                                <th class="head-name"><span>item</span></th>
                                <th class="head-item-price"><span>price</span></th>
                                <th class="head-price"><span>total</span></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>


                                    <tr>
                                    <td class="product-quantity">
                                            <span>1</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="product-name">

                                            <span class="name">Πίτα γύρος κοτόπουλο</span>

                                            <dl class="variation">
                        <dt class="variation-euro020">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-euro020"><p>διπλό ζυμαράκι</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-"><p>Με υλικά της επιλογής σας</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-"><p>πατάτες</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-"><p>ντομάτα</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-"><p>τζατζίκι</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-"><p>μουστάρδα</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-"><p>σως μουστάδρας</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-"><p>μαγιονέζα</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-"><p>ροζ σως</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-euro020">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-euro020"><p>μαρούλι</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-euro050">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-euro050"><p>πιπεριά</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-euro050">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-euro050"><p>καλαμπόκι</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-euro070">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-euro070"><p>τυρί τριμμένο</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-euro070">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-euro070"><p>σαγανάκι</p>
</dd>

                        <dt class="variation-euro070">+:</dt>
                        <dd class="variation-euro070"><p>φέτα</p>
</dd>
                    </dl>                                           
                                            <dl class="extras">

                                                                                            </dl>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="product-item-price">
                                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.30</span></span>
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="product-price">
                                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.30</span></span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>


                                    <tr>
                                    <td class="product-quantity">
                                            <span>1</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="product-name">

                                            <span class="name">Ντοματοσαλάτα</span>


                                            <dl class="extras">

                                                                                            </dl>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="product-item-price">
                                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.20</span></span>
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="product-price">
                                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.20</span></span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>


                                    <tr>
                                    <td class="product-quantity">
                                            <span>1</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="product-name">

                                            <span class="name">Χωριάτικη</span>


                                            <dl class="extras">

                                                                                            </dl>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="product-item-price">
                                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.50</span></span>
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="product-price">
                                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.50</span></span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                                    </tbody>

                        <tfoot>                         
                                                                                                <tr>
                                        <td class="total-name"><span>Subtotal</span></td>
                                        <td class="total-item-price"></td>
                                        <td class="total-quantity"></td>
                                        <td class="total-price"><span><span class="amount">&euro;16.00</span></span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="total-name"><span>Shipping</span></td>
                                        <td class="total-item-price"></td>
                                        <td class="total-quantity"></td>
                                        <td class="total-price"><span>Delivery</span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="total-name"><span>Total</span></td>
                                        <td class="total-item-price"></td>
                                        <td class="total-quantity"></td>
                                        <td class="total-price"><span><span class="amount">&euro;16.00</span></span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                                    </tfoot>
                    </table>

                                    </div><!-- .order-items -->


                <div class="order-notes">

                                    </div><!-- .order-notes -->




                <div class="order-colophon">
                    <div class="colophon-policies">
                                            </div>

                    <div class="colophon-imprint">
                                            </div>  

                                    </div><!-- .order-colophon -->

                </article><!-- .content -->






        </div><!-- #page -->
```

CSS:

```
    /*
 * Template: Default
 */

/* Simple CSS Reset and Print options
------------------------------------------*/


html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, table, ol, ul, dl, li, dt, dd {
    border: 0 none;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


/* Template Page Layout
------------------------------------------*/


/* Main Body */
body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

ul {
    margin-bottom: 1.25em;
}

li,
dt,
dd  {
    padding: 0.375em 0;
}

dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}

p + p {
    margin-top: 1.25em;
}

address {
    font-style: normal;
}

/* Basic Table Styling */
table {
    page-break-inside: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after: auto; 
    border-bottom: 0.12em solid #bbb;
}

td,
th {
    padding: 0.375em 0.75em 0.375em 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

td img,
th img {
    vertical-align: top;
}

th {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 1.25em;
}

tfoot {
    display: table-row-group;
}

/* Page Margins & Basic Stylings */
#page {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.content {
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.content + .content {
    page-break-before: always;
}

h1,
h2 {
    font-size: 1.572em;
}

.order-branding,
.order-addresses,
.order-info,
.order-items,
.order-notes,
.order-thanks,
.order-colophon {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.order-items {
    page-break-before: auto;
    page-break-after: auto;
}

/* Order Branding */
.order-branding .company-logo {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

/* Order Addresses */
.order-addresses {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.order-addresses:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.billing-address {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.shipping-address {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.order-addresses.no-shipping-address .shipping-address {
    display: none;
}

/*
.order-addresses.no-shipping-address .billing-address {
    margin-left: 50%;
}
*/

/* Switch the addresses for invoices */

/* Order Info */
.order-info ul {
    border-top: 0.24em solid black;
}

.order-info li {
    border-bottom: 0.12em solid #bbb;
}

.order-info li strong {
    min-width: 18%;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 0.35em;
}

/* Order Items */
.order-items {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.order-items .head-name,
.order-items .product-name,
.order-items .total-name {
    width: 50%;
}

.order-items .head-quantity,
.order-items .product-quantity,
.order-items .total-quantity,
.order-items .head-item-price,
.order-items .product-item-price,
.order-items .total-item-price {
    width: 15%;
}

.order-items .head-price,
.order-items .product-price,
.order-items .total-price {
    width: 20%;
}

.order-items p {
    display: inline;
}

.order-items small,
.order-items dt,
.order-items dd {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 150%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.order-items dt,
.order-items dd {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.order-items dt {
    clear: left;
    padding-right: 0.2em;
}

.order-items tfoot tr:first-child,
.order-items tfoot tr:last-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.order-items tfoot tr:last-child .total-price .amount:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.order-items tfoot tr:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0.24em solid black;
}

/* Order Notes */
.order-notes {
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 6em;
}

.order-notes h4 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* Order Thanks */
.order-thanks {
    margin-left: 50%;
}

/* Order Colophon */
.order-colophon {
    font-size: 0.785em;
    line-height: 150%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.colophon-policies {
    margin-bottom: 1.25em;
}


/* CSS Media Queries for Print
------------------------------------------*/


@media print {
    body {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .content {
        /* Remove padding to not generate empty follow up pages */
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child()`. The CSS you need is:

```css
.order-items table tr > *:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

**Working Snippet**

```css
/*
 * Template: Default
 */


/* Simple CSS Reset and Print options
------------------------------------------*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
a,
table,
ol,
ul,
dl,
li,
dt,
dd {
  border: 0 none;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* Template Page Layout
------------------------------------------*/


/* Main Body */

body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

ul {
  margin-bottom: 1.25em;
}

li,
dt,
dd {
  padding: 0.375em 0;
}

dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}

p + p {
  margin-top: 1.25em;
}

address {
  font-style: normal;
}


/* Basic Table Styling */

table {
  page-break-inside: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: auto;
  border-bottom: 0.12em solid #bbb;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.375em 0.75em 0.375em 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

td img,
th img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

th {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
}

tfoot {
  display: table-row-group;
}


/* Page Margins & Basic Stylings */

#page {
  margin-left: 10px !important;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.content {
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.content + .content {
  page-break-before: always;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-size: 1.572em;
}

.order-branding,
.order-addresses,
.order-info,
.order-items,
.order-notes,
.order-thanks,
.order-colophon {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.order-items {
  page-break-before: auto;
  page-break-after: auto;
}


/* Order Branding */

.order-branding .company-logo {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}


/* Order Addresses */

.order-addresses {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.order-addresses:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.billing-address {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.shipping-address {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.order-addresses.no-shipping-address .shipping-address {
  display: none;
}


/*
.order-addresses.no-shipping-address .billing-address {
 margin-left: 50%;
}
*/


/* Switch the addresses for invoices */


/* Order Info */

.order-info ul {
  border-top: 0.24em solid black;
}

.order-info li {
  border-bottom: 0.12em solid #bbb;
}

.order-info li strong {
  min-width: 18%;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 0.35em;
}


/* Order Items */

.order-items {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.order-items .head-name,
.order-items .product-name,
.order-items .total-name {
  width: 50%;
}

.order-items .head-quantity,
.order-items .product-quantity,
.order-items .total-quantity,
.order-items .head-item-price,
.order-items .product-item-price,
.order-items .total-item-price {
  width: 15%;
}

.order-items .head-price,
.order-items .product-price,
.order-items .total-price {
  width: 20%;
}

.order-items p {
  display: inline;
}

.order-items small,
.order-items dt,
.order-items dd {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 150%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.order-items dt,
.order-items dd {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.order-items dt {
  clear: left;
  padding-right: 0.2em;
}

.order-items tfoot tr:first-child,
.order-items tfoot tr:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.order-items tfoot tr:last-child .total-price .amount:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.order-items tfoot tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0.24em solid black;
}


/* Order Notes */

.order-notes {
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 6em;
}

.order-notes h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* Order Thanks */

.order-thanks {
  margin-left: 50%;
}


/* Order Colophon */

.order-colophon {
  font-size: 0.785em;
  line-height: 150%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.colophon-policies {
  margin-bottom: 1.25em;
}


/* CSS Media Queries for Print
------------------------------------------*/

@media print {
  body {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .content {
    /* Remove padding to not generate empty follow up pages */
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.order-items table tr > *:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <article class="content">

    <div class="company-info">
      <h1 class="company-name">Flouskounis Food</h1>
      <div class="company-address">
        <p>2610 424342, Νοταρά 85</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="order-addresses">

      <div class="billing-address">
        <h3>Πελάτης:</h3>
        <address>
          customer name<br/>Κυρία<br/>address<br/>ισόγειο<br/>city<br/>Πελοπόννησος<br/>26225
        </address>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- .order-addresses -->
    phone
    <div class="order-items">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="head-quantity"><span>quantity</span></th>
            <th class="head-name"><span>item</span></th>
            <th class="head-item-price"><span>price</span></th>
            <th class="head-price"><span>total</span></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>


          <tr>
            <td class="product-quantity">
              <span>1</span>
            </td>
            <td class="product-name">

              <span class="name">Πίτα γύρος κοτόπουλο</span>

              <dl class="variation">
                <dt class="variation-euro020">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-euro020">
                  <p>διπλό ζυμαράκι</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-">
                  <p>Με υλικά της επιλογής σας</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-">
                  <p>πατάτες</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-">
                  <p>ντομάτα</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-">
                  <p>τζατζίκι</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-">
                  <p>μουστάρδα</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-">
                  <p>σως μουστάδρας</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-">
                  <p>μαγιονέζα</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-">
                  <p>ροζ σως</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-euro020">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-euro020">
                  <p>μαρούλι</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-euro050">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-euro050">
                  <p>πιπεριά</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-euro050">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-euro050">
                  <p>καλαμπόκι</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-euro070">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-euro070">
                  <p>τυρί τριμμένο</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-euro070">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-euro070">
                  <p>σαγανάκι</p>
                </dd>

                <dt class="variation-euro070">+:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-euro070">
                  <p>φέτα</p>
                </dd>
              </dl>
              <dl class="extras">

              </dl>
            </td>
            <td class="product-item-price">
              <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.30</span></span>
            </td>

            <td class="product-price">
              <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.30</span></span>
            </td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <td class="product-quantity">
              <span>1</span>
            </td>
            <td class="product-name">

              <span class="name">Ντοματοσαλάτα</span>


              <dl class="extras">

              </dl>
            </td>
            <td class="product-item-price">
              <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.20</span></span>
            </td>

            <td class="product-price">
              <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.20</span></span>
            </td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <td class="product-quantity">
              <span>1</span>
            </td>
            <td class="product-name">

              <span class="name">Χωριάτικη</span>


              <dl class="extras">

              </dl>
            </td>
            <td class="product-item-price">
              <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.50</span></span>
            </td>

            <td class="product-price">
              <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.50</span></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td class="total-name"><span>Subtotal</span></td>
            <td class="total-item-price"></td>
            <td class="total-quantity"></td>
            <td class="total-price"><span><span class="amount">&euro;16.00</span></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="total-name"><span>Shipping</span></td>
            <td class="total-item-price"></td>
            <td class="total-quantity"></td>
            <td class="total-price"><span>Delivery</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="total-name"><span>Total</span></td>
            <td class="total-item-price"></td>
            <td class="total-quantity"></td>
            <td class="total-price"><span><span class="amount">&euro;16.00</span></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>

    </div>
    <!-- .order-items -->

    <div class="order-notes">

    </div>
    <!-- .order-notes -->

    <div class="order-colophon">
      <div class="colophon-policies">
      </div>

      <div class="colophon-imprint">
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- .order-colophon -->

  </article>
  <!-- .content -->

</div>
<!-- #page -->
```

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks, any idea on how to make quantity column be like 10% width of the table instead of 30% ?

Comment: @K.Lykoudis Just add `width="10%"` to the corresponding `<th>`. Or just use `.head-quantity {width: 10%;}` in CSS.

Comment: Tried that already, its 15% on the css but it takes about 35%. check it on the fiddle, even if i put it 1% it stays the same, it gets smaller if i make it over 60% (????) it had confused me alot..

Comment: @K.Lykoudis I understand what you are trying to tell, but this is what is possible at max. That's how tables behave.

Comment: So i cannot make quantity column to be smaller in width and not taking 35% of total width to show 1 or 2 digits?

Comment: Nevermind, i set: 

table-layout:fixed;

and now i can set their width to whatever i like! thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: Yeah worked great, i updated my previous comment check :)

Comment: @K.Lykoudis That's really nice to hear. Enjoy.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ay7ys32L/4/

there is the complete fixed fiddle if anyone whats to test it. Thank you very much man, Be good.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that one the row of quantity is have 50% - class- total-name

All other td elements of that quantity column are with 15% except Subtotal column which is overwriting the width of whole column.Added that Subtotal class to 15% will fix it.

codepen url for reference- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BzNmzp

```
      <div id="page">





              <article class="content">


                <div class="company-info">
                  <h1 class="company-name">Flouskounis Food</h1>                        <div class="company-address"><p>2610 424342, Νοταρά 85</p>
      </div>
                </div>

              <div class="order-addresses">

                <div class="billing-address">
                  <h3>Πελάτης:</h3>
                  <address>

                    customer name<br/>Κυρία<br/>address<br/>ισόγειο<br/>city<br/>Πελοπόννησος<br/>26225
                  </address>
                </div>

              </div><!-- .order-addresses -->
              phone             
              <div class="order-items">
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="head-quantity"><span>quantity</span></th>
                      <th class="head-name"><span>item</span></th>
                      <th class="head-item-price"><span>price</span></th>
                      <th class="head-price"><span>total</span></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>


                        <tr>
                        <td class="product-quantity">
                            <span>1</span>
                          </td>
                          <td class="product-name">

                            <span class="name">Πίτα γύρος κοτόπουλο</span>

                            <dl class="variation">
                  <dt class="variation-euro020">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-euro020"><p>διπλό ζυμαράκι</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-"><p>Με υλικά της επιλογής σας</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-"><p>πατάτες</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-"><p>ντομάτα</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-"><p>τζατζίκι</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-"><p>μουστάρδα</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-"><p>σως μουστάδρας</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-"><p>μαγιονέζα</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-"><p>ροζ σως</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-euro020">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-euro020"><p>μαρούλι</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-euro050">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-euro050"><p>πιπεριά</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-euro050">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-euro050"><p>καλαμπόκι</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-euro070">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-euro070"><p>τυρί τριμμένο</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-euro070">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-euro070"><p>σαγανάκι</p>
      </dd>

                  <dt class="variation-euro070">+:</dt>
                  <dd class="variation-euro070"><p>φέτα</p>
      </dd>
                </dl>                                           
                            <dl class="extras">

                                                    </dl>
                          </td>
                          <td class="product-item-price">
                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.30</span></span>
                          </td>

                          <td class="product-price">
                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.30</span></span>
                          </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                        <td class="product-quantity">
                            <span>1</span>
                          </td>
                          <td class="product-name">

                            <span class="name">Ντοματοσαλάτα</span>


                            <dl class="extras">

                                                    </dl>
                          </td>
                          <td class="product-item-price">
                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.20</span></span>
                          </td>

                          <td class="product-price">
                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.20</span></span>
                          </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                        <td class="product-quantity">
                            <span>1</span>
                          </td>
                          <td class="product-name">

                            <span class="name">Χωριάτικη</span>


                            <dl class="extras">

                                                    </dl>
                          </td>
                          <td class="product-item-price">
                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.50</span></span>
                          </td>

                          <td class="product-price">
                            <span><span class="amount">&euro;5.50</span></span>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                                                </tbody>

                  <tfoot>                           
                                                      <tr>
                          <td class="total-name"><span>Subtotal</span></td>
                          <td class="total-item-price"></td>
                          <td class="total-quantity"></td>
                          <td class="total-price"><span><span class="amount">&euro;16.00</span></span></td>
                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                          <td class="total-name"><span>Shipping</span></td>
                          <td class="total-item-price"></td>
                          <td class="total-quantity"></td>
                          <td class="total-price"><span>Delivery</span></td>
                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                          <td class="total-name"><span>Total</span></td>
                          <td class="total-item-price"></td>
                          <td class="total-quantity"></td>
                          <td class="total-price"><span><span class="amount">&euro;16.00</span></span></td>
                        </tr>
                                                </tfoot>
                </table>

                        </div><!-- .order-items -->


              <div class="order-notes">

                        </div><!-- .order-notes -->




              <div class="order-colophon">
                <div class="colophon-policies">
                            </div>

                <div class="colophon-imprint">
                            </div>  

                        </div><!-- .order-colophon -->

              </article><!-- .content -->






          </div><!-- #page -->
```

CSS:

```
      /*
       * Template: Default
       */

      /* Simple CSS Reset and Print options
      ------------------------------------------*/


      html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, table, ol, ul, dl, li, dt, dd {
        border: 0 none;
        font: inherit;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: baseline;
      }

      body {
        line-height: 1;
      }

      ol,
      ul {
        list-style: none;
      }

      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
      }


      /* Template Page Layout
      ------------------------------------------*/


      /* Main Body */
      body {
        background: #fff;
        color: #000;
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
        line-height: 1.25em;
      }

      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4 {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 1.2em;
      }

      ul {
        margin-bottom: 1.25em;
      }

      li,
      dt,
      dd  {
        padding: 0.375em 0;
      }

      dt {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      p + p {
        margin-top: 1.25em;
      }

      address {
        font-style: normal;
      }

      /* Basic Table Styling */
      table {
        page-break-inside: auto;
        width: 100%;
      }

      tr {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        page-break-after: auto; 
        border-bottom: 0.12em solid #bbb;
      }

      td,
      th {
        padding: 0.375em 0.75em 0.375em 0;
        vertical-align: top;
      }

      td img,
      th img {
        vertical-align: top;
      }

      th {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        padding-bottom: 1.25em;
      }

      tfoot {
        display: table-row-group;
      }

      /* Page Margins & Basic Stylings */
      #page {
        margin-left: 10px !important;
        margin-right: 10px;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      .content {
        padding-left: 2%;
        padding-right: 2%;
        padding-top: 2%;
        padding-bottom: 2%;
      }

      .content + .content {
        page-break-before: always;
      }

      h1,
      h2 {
        font-size: 1.572em;
      }

      .order-branding,
      .order-addresses,
      .order-info,
      .order-items,
      .order-notes,
      .order-thanks,
      .order-colophon {
        margin-bottom: 3em;
      }

      .order-items {
        page-break-before: auto;
        page-break-after: auto;
      }

      /* Order Branding */
      .order-branding .company-logo {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
      }

      /* Order Addresses */
      .order-addresses {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .order-addresses:after {
        content: ".";
          display: block;
          height: 0;
          clear: both;
          visibility: hidden;
      }

      .billing-address {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
      }

      .shipping-address {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
      }

      .order-addresses.no-shipping-address .shipping-address {
        display: none;
      }

      /*
      .order-addresses.no-shipping-address .billing-address {
        margin-left: 50%;
      }
      */

      /* Switch the addresses for invoices */

      /* Order Info */
      .order-info ul {
        border-top: 0.24em solid black;
      }

      .order-info li {
        border-bottom: 0.12em solid #bbb;
      }

      .order-info li strong {
        min-width: 18%;
        font-weight: normal;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-right: 0.35em;
      }

      /* Order Items */
      .order-items {
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
      }

      .order-items .head-name,
      .order-items .product-name,
      {
        width: 50%;
      }

      /*added .order-items .total-name to 15%*/
      .order-items .total-name 
      .order-items .head-quantity,
      .order-items .product-quantity,
      .order-items .total-quantity,
      .order-items .head-item-price,
      .order-items .product-item-price,
      .order-items .total-item-price {
        width: 15%;
      }

      .order-items .head-price,
      .order-items .product-price,
      .order-items .total-price {
        width: 20%;
      }

      .order-items p {
        display: inline;
      }

      .order-items small,
      .order-items dt,
      .order-items dd {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 150%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .order-items dt,
      .order-items dd {
        display: block;
        float: left;
      }

      .order-items dt {
        clear: left;
        padding-right: 0.2em;
      }

      .order-items tfoot tr:first-child,
      .order-items tfoot tr:last-child {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .order-items tfoot tr:last-child .total-price .amount:first-child {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .order-items tfoot tr:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0.24em solid black;
      }

      /* Order Notes */
      .order-notes {
        margin-top: 3em;
        margin-bottom: 6em;
      }

      .order-notes h4 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }

      /* Order Thanks */
      .order-thanks {
        margin-left: 50%;
      }

      /* Order Colophon */
      .order-colophon {
        font-size: 0.785em;
        line-height: 150%;
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }

      .colophon-policies {
        margin-bottom: 1.25em;
      }


      /* CSS Media Queries for Print
      ------------------------------------------*/


      @media print {
        body {
          font-size: 14px;
        }

        .content {
          /* Remove padding to not generate empty follow up pages */
          padding-bottom: 0;
        }
      }


      .head-item-price{
         visibility:hidden;
       }

      .product-item-price .amount
      {
        display:none;
       }
```

Hope this is helpful for you

Please let me know if you need help :)